# SSIS File Watcher task on Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have installed ssis file watcher task on my laptop which is running a local copy of sql server 2012 and visual studio 2010.

My question is once i have built the ssis package and wanted to run it on a different server do i also need to install the ssis file watcher addon on the server as well as my laptop??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.
SSIS does not come with an in-built file watcher task, so it sounds like you installed something like this: http://www.sqlis.com/post/file-watcher-task.aspx.  In order for the server to be able to execute the package it will be looking for the file watcher ell in the GAC.  The task I noted here has an msi file which will take care of the installation process.  If the task does not, the least that you need to do is just get the dll in the gac, it does not need to go in the sql server folders which are only necessary for development.